# How do I display a certain amount of words per line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a list:

```
names = ['dog','cat','mouse','moose','rabbit','horse','apple','banana','orange']
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
dog cat mouse moose rabbit horse
apple banana orange
```

So basically a max of six words per line displayed when printed.

I'm honestly clueless where to start, because a for loop as such will display 1 per line:

```
for i in names:
   print(i)

output -->
dog
cat
mouse
moose
rabbit
horse
apple
banana
orange
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You could use `range` with a step to split it up:

```
names = ['dog','cat','mouse','moose','rabbit','horse','apple','banana','orange']

for i in range(0, len(names), 6):
    print(names[i:i + 6])
```

Comment: I want to print the words so they're not a part of a list.

Comment: @ajkey94: Then join them together with `' '.join(words)`

Answer (score 0):

Poor man's version:

```
counter = 0
for i in names:
    if counter == 5:
        counter = 0
        print i
    else:
        print i,
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Another way of `print '\n',` is simply `print`

Comment: True, and i also made a mistake in my code too, fixing it up [=

Comment: now you have repeated `print i,`

Answer (score 0):

Using textwrap with a maximum 35 characters line width, which helps if you have words of varying sizes:

```
import textwrap
names = ['dog','cat','mouse','moose','rabbit','horse','apple','banana','orange']
for l in textwrap.wrap("\n".join(names),35):
    print l
```

This is useful if you want to right justify your output. I think splitting on the number of words is useful if you want to generate white-space delimited columns.

Comment: -1 I could have 35 character words

Comment: for example :) joking aside, this is just a variant in case the real intention is to align lines.

Comment: @jamylak, also all suggested duplicates point out evenly sized chunks questions.

Comment: alright, point taken. Add that info to your question so I can remove downvote